# Weird behavior with two output parameters in a stored proc called from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've modified an existing strored procedure. It originally had one ouput parameter in the stored proc and it was set up as follows in the c# code that called it:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Var1Param", SqlDbType.BigInt);
if (Var1 == 0)
                cmd.Parameters["@Var1"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                cmd.Parameters["@Var"].Value = Var1;
            cmd.Parameters["@Var1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Get Var1
Var1= dataMorph.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["@Var1"].Value.ToString());
```

Just to clarify, this parameter was declared as OUTPUT in the stored proc but as inputoutput in the C# code. This worked fine.

I have added another parameter to the same stored procedure and I want to retrieve both from the C# code. The C# code now is as follows:

```
  SqlParameter Var1Param;

             if (VAR1 == 0)
                 Var1Param = new SqlParameter("@Var1", DBNull.Value);
             else
                 Var1Param = new SqlParameter("@Var1",Var1) ;

             Var1Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput ;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(Var1Param);
```

Again this parameter is declared as output in the stored proc but inputoutput in the c# code.
Here is the new parameter. This is declared as output in the stored procedured. Here is the C# code.

```
SqlParameter Var2Param = new SqlParameter("@Var2", 0);
            Var2Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Var2Param);
```

I only want to output the second parameter as you can see. The assignment of 0 to this parameter seems to be a standard practice despite the fact it's an output variable only. I'm not sure if need to give it a type.

Now the execution

```
            // Execute
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();

            // Get DonationID
            Var1 = dataMorph.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["@Var1"].Value.ToString());

            //Get Supersession Daf ID return param to see if new DAF was created
            Var2 = dataMorph.ToInt64(cmd.Parameters["@Var2"].Value.ToString());
```

What happens is that both the var1 and vaf2 parameters contain the value that was assigned to @Var2 parameter in the stored procedure. I have read that any number of  parameters and parameter types can be used but it seems like the value assigned to @Var2 is overwriting the Value that had been passed in or assigned to Var1.

Any advice? I know I can work around this by having multiple result sets and putting my output values in the second result set but I'd rather not deal with Kludges unless I have to. I've seen a lot of posts about the odd state of parameters after they return from stored procs and are accessed in c#. Is this type of behavior a bug?

---

I  will point out that I'm using executenonquery because the SP does an update. sarfeast is using execute scalar. I'm assuming that this shouldn't make any difference but I'll ask if anyone has any ideas on why this is happening. I modified the code by specifying sizes for the sqlparameters and now the value for var2 is showing up in var1 and var2 is Null!!!

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The code the you've listed looks fair enough to me, you can certainly use parameters in this way to return values from the SQL. However you've only posted half of the code, the other half being in the Stroed Procedure. If you could post the SQL that would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work just fine so perhaps this has something to do with the logic in your stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Outs 
    @var1 INT OUTPUT,
    @var2 INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  @var1 = 1,
            @var2 = 2
END
GO

        var connectionstring = @"server=rickshaw;database=becak;Trusted_Connection=true;";

        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Outs", conn))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@var1", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@var2", 0);

                cmd.Parameters["@var1"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@var1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

                cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();

                var var1 = cmd.Parameters["@var1"].Value;
                var var2 = cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value;

                Console.WriteLine("var1=" + var1);
                Console.WriteLine("var2=" + var2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I have considered that as a possibility and, ironically, someone on an sql forum where I posted this same question told me that this should be on a C# forum :-).